# Списковая инициализация

Tags: c++

В чём смысл такой инициализации переменной?: `int x = {}`
`int x{}`
. В чём отличие от простой инициализации `int x = 5` `int x = 0`?

Comment: Именно пустые скобки? Инициализация по умолчанию для данного типа (0 для целых, 0.0 для плавающей запятой, `nullptr` для указателя и т.д.).

Comment: Нет, просто как пример написал, хоть int x = {5}, просто непонятно чем такая инициализация отличается от классической.

Comment: Невозможностью сужающего преобразования в первую очередь.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization

Comment: есть такой вариант - `int x{}` vs `int x()`. Кто на такое не натыкался, тот не писал на плюсах

Comment: Никакого глубокого смысла, кроме как отодвинуть начинающих подальше от старого доброго Си

Comment: си хорош, но я бы добавил ему чуточки строгости типов.